# Send an email using php with mysql data included

Tags: mysql, php

I'm trying to send a list of recent entries into a mysql table via email once a week using cron jobs. Typically to call the list of recent entries I use this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE PurchaseDate < '$TODAY' AND PurchaseDate > '$LASTWEEK'")
or die(mysql_error());
while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

But obviously I can't put this code into the `$message` variable in php mail.

Any ideas?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE PurchaseDate < '$TODAY' AND PurchaseDate > '$LASTWEEK'") or die(mysql_error());
$entries = 'Entries: '; 
while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $entries .= $list[entry] . ', ';
}

mail('someone@test.com', 'Stock', $entries);
```

This is just an example. Not sure what your table looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The mail functions takes a string, and you are returning an array.

So you need to implode it `implode(',', $list);` or build a string with the result set.

You should use PHPMailer, Zend Mail or Swift_Mailer libraries that are safer and prevent for example from header injection.

Comment: When I do this it works, but it only shows me the first result.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE blank = 'blank' AND blank2 ='blank2'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows < 1) {
    throw new Exception('There is no user who qualifies...');
}
if(!$result) {
throw new Exception('An Error Occurred..');
}

//mail off whatever you need to each user that qualifies based on your query criteria..

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$firstname = stripslashes($row['firstname']);
$lastname = stripslashes($row['lastname']);
$email = stripslashes($row['email']);
//and any other variables you need for the email...

$subject = 'Some Subject';
$message = 'Hello '.$firstname.' blah..blah...';

mail($email, $subject, $message);
//do something else...
echo 'All users emailed.';
}

}

catch (Exception $e) {

echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

Comment: Realizing now..that you only needed the entries not each user...sorry.  I only had a few seconds to scan your request.